# how to detect finished successful build_runner?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

We need to be notified of the successful completion (or failure to re-run) of build_runner.
I need to call its command in a bash file, but the program
It does not close after the operation completes (successfully or unsuccessfully).

I want to use it in build automation steps (ci/cd).
Please help on this particular issue thanks.

I use build_runner like below:

```
flutter pub run build_runner watch  --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the **watch** and **serve** commands are intended for iterative development and do not set the exit code because they run for multiple builds and terminate when killed by the user.

I using **build** command and resolved problem:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

refrence: [github/issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/3362)